# Grey Lines when batch processing a self build arcmap tool with model builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, modelbuilder, batch

I've used ArcMap 10.3 ModelBuilder for a simple model that iterates the raster data in a folder and writes the result of raster calculation to another specified folder. [image]
Instead of the specified input folder name and output filename I rename them to Input and Output. Processing this within ModelBuilder works fine.
But as I have a few folders to process, I tried the batch processing mode which ended with grey lines for the output file names.

[image]

How can I modify my model in order to be able to process this simple model in batch mode?

Edit 1:
I'm trying to iterate the rasters in the folders (examp: E:/1/path1raw1/; E:/1/path2raw2/; E:/1/path3raw3/) and try to save them to another folder (examp E:/2/path1raw1/; E:/2/path2raw2/; E:/2/path3raw3/) after calculation by specifying the output as E:/2/path1raw1/%name%.tif. I think the problem is that it can not iterate the output folders based on input folders. But I can not find a solution yet.

Comment: I have had success circumventing this small problem by setting the batch environments to the desired folder, then using the "Check Values" check mark button on the right, this will often unlock those grey boxes.  Hopefully that  helps.

Comment: After your comment, I've tried but unfortunately, that did not work for me. I think the problem is, I am iterating the rasters in the input folder and try to save them to a folder by specifying a name. So when I try to use the batch mode it performed the calculations for the first folder but stopped afterward.

Comment: To my experience, batch processing in model builder always lack in processing such problem. I used to use CalculateValue tool in many occasions to achieve customisation that I need. After a while you start to realise learning python is the best way forward and better investment of your time.